# angularjs required field validation working incorrectly

Tags: angularjs

I modified one of the starter angularjs demos and I'm having trouble getting the required field to work correctly. I can successfully prevent blank submissions but the "required field" will pop up after a valid submission. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
    $scope.addTodo = function () {
      if ($scope.myform.$valid) {
          $scope.todos.push({
              text: $scope.todoText,
              done: false
          });
          $scope.todoText = '';
      }
    };

    <form name="myform">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30" placeholder="add new todo here" ng-required="true">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add" ng-click="addTodo()">
    </form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RJFd8/

Comment: it is working fine for me. Testing in Safari.

Comment: I am seeing the issue in Chrome 30.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 30 as well

Answer (score 2):

Try adding    novalidate

to your `form`

Comment: If I add novalidate, I don't seee the "required field" validation